# How to get specific tags value from HTML table

Tags: java, html, jsoup

First i want to apologise for my english. I am new with programming in java and also in Jsoup. i want to get some data from website. Information in the website is given in HTML tabel.i don't need not all fields from the tabel. I use this;

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.emo.nl/barges/en.html")
  .data("query", "Java")
  .userAgent("Mozilla")
  .cookie("auth", "token")
  .timeout(3000)
  .post();


           Element table1 =  doc.select("table").first();//.getElementsByTag("td");//.getElementsByTag("td")

            String body = table1.toString();
            Document docb = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(body);
            Element bbd = docb.body();
            String hhk = bbd.toString();



          System.out.println(hhk);
```

result of this code gives me all Tabel in String. As follow;

```
<body>
 <table> 
  <tbody> 
   <tr> 
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Bargeno.</th> 
    <th>Reported present</th> 
    <th>Busy</th> 
    <th>Starting</th> 
    <th>Harbour</th> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>AMETHYST</td> 
    <td>2327085</td> 
    <td>*</td> 
    <td>Busy</td> 
    <td>19-03-2014 &nbsp;spil 1</td> 
    <td>HH</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>AMETHYST 2</td> 
    <td>2327086</td> 
    <td>*</td> 
    <td>Busy</td> 
    <td>19-03-2014 &nbsp;spil 1</td> 
    <td>HH</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td>AQUAPOLIS</td> 
    <td>6105002</td> 
    <td>*</td> 
    <td>&nbsp;</td> 
    <td>19-03-2014 &nbsp;spil 1</td> 
    <td>HH</td> 
   </tr> 
</tbody> 
 </table>
</body>
```

This is too much information for me i want to make two variabel lets say;

```
private String naam;
private String date;

and in name variabel i want to store first <td> tag (AMETHYST)
and in date variabel i want to put  fifth <td> tag (19-03-2014)
```

Is there any way to do this thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to read the elements at the specified index:

```
String naam = bbd.getElementsByTag("td").get(0).text();
String date = bbd.getElementsByTag("td").get(4).text();

System.out.println(naam + " " + date);
```

Gives,

```
AMETHYST 19-03-2014  spil 1
```

**EDIT:**
Since the td contains `&nbps; spil 1` you would see that getting retrieved too. In case you want to eliminate and the `&nbsp;` presence is consistent then;

```
System.out.println(naam + " " + date.substring(0, date.indexOf('\u00A0') - 1));
```

Gives,

```
AMETHYST 19-03-2014
```

**EDIT 2:** Based on OP's query on getting the collection of all 1st `td`s within the table use something like:

```
Elements tds = table1.select(" > tbody > tr > td:eq(0)");

for (Element el : tds) {
    System.out.println(el.text());
}
```

Where  `> tbody > tr > td:eq(0)` pulls out the 0th index td against every tr encountered within your `table1`

Output,

```
AQUAPOLIS
AQUAPOLIS
IMPERIAL 7
CHIMO
...
```

For more information on the selector syntax refer to [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

Comment: Thank you very much it's work perfect. I can't vote on you because of my reputation.

Comment: I have one more question, there are three different data that i have to get how do i get all three data(AMETHYST, AMETHYST 2, AQUAPOLIS) i have tried something with (Element getAll : bbd) whiteout any success can you please help me.

Comment: @user3360123 updated with the 2nd edit, that should work for your case